# infragistics web dialog window

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, infragistics

Our team has a web app built on asp.net (C#) and uses some infragistics asp.net controls. I'm having serious problems (in particular) with the infragistics web dialog window (IGWD) since I started to move the html of the app to html5 and using bootstrap 3 as the css framework.
I believe that some properties like table-layout:fixed and table widths that bootstrap 3 uses are messing up the IGWD control. But if I remove those properties from bootstrap css I mess all the framework and thus, all the app.
Any ideas where I should start? Already read the infragistics documentation but is not as good as one might think and didn't help me at all on this particular issue :-(
Thanks in advance for all your help and patience.

Comment: Do you have an example that can be used for debugging.  Also what specific version of the Infragistics controls are you using?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I'm starting to get some results - what I did was just follow the guidelines and samples of this guy = http://www.ezineasp.net/post/AJAX-Calendar-Extender-CSS-Theme.aspx and adapt his ideas to infragistics controls.

So, I created my own cssclass and contextualize all infragistics web dialog window classes under my own! But I had to go codebehind to make sure some attributes are set the way I want. For example, I had to add these lines

```
wdwAddCurso.WindowState = DialogWindowState.Normal;
wdwAddCurso.InitialLocation = DialogWindowPosition.Centered;
```

otherwise I couldn't get the window to stay where I wanted it even if I had

```
<ig:WebDialogWindow ID="wdwAddCurso" runat="server" Width="640px" Height="480px" InitialLocation="Centered" Moveable="true"  Modal="True" StyleSetName="RubberBlack" ModalBackgroundCssClass="igdw_RubberBlackModalBackground">
<ContentPane FrameBorder="true">
<Template>
<uc1:CursosAdd01 runat="server" ID="CursosAdd011" />
<div class="text-center">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="button" Text="Fechar" />
</div>
</Template>
</ContentPane>
<Header>
<CloseBox Visible="false" />
</Header>
<AutoPostBackFlags WindowStateChange="On" />
</ig:WebDialogWindow>
```

in the aspx file.
Anyway, thanks for the answer!
The version we're using is Infragistics4.Web.v10.3, Version=10.3.20103.2217.

And the result I'm getting is this (not the final result we desire but...as I've said before, we are getting somewhere):
[you can see a screenshot here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=760987E7A0337A1%21309)